# What's the simplest way to center an image vertically within a line of text?

Tags: html, html-table, vertical-alignment

Presently I use:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td><a href="cv.pdf" target="_blank">
    <img src="graphics/pdf.gif" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
    <td width="10px"></td> <!--that just spaces the image from the text-->
    <td>
        <a href="cv.pdf" target="_blank"><em>Download CV.</em></a>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Pretty clunky but renders perfectly. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: make something centered vertically... simply? hope you don't care about cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @Moses — this is very simple to achieve in a cross browser compatible fashion.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice they were tables when I made the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the following CSS property on your image:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the table, combine the two anchors into one, remove the `width` and `height` on the `img` tag, remove the `em` tag, *then* use `vertical-align` to center the image. You can also use `margin` to add some space between the text and the image, and `font-style` for the italic text.

HTML:

```
<p class="cv">
    <a href="cv.pdf">
        <img src="image/source.png" /> Download CV.
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.cv {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cv a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}

.cv img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.cv a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

See, much better. Removing `width` and `height` makes images display better (because browsers suck at image interpolation. If you need a different size than is available you should do the resizing yourself.), and removing `target="_blank"` will cause less annoyance for your users.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/kZeCt/1/